# I want to add some classes to my nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

i use `.selected` for topnav and `.active` for sub navs

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav uppercase col-md-10">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw open selected">
        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
            <li class="active"><a href="http://www.example.com/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw">
        <a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-puzzle"></i>example</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">example1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/2">example2</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Sexample3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/4">example4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

what i want is when i click and redirect to an other page i want javascript to detect the url of the page and active the links inside my navbar that contains the same href value as the url + add selected class to the parent of `.dropdown-menu-fw`

```
var url = window.location;
console.log(url);
$('.dropdown-menu-fw li a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
$('.dropdown-menu-fw li a').filter(function() {
return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = window.location.href;

$('.dropdown-menu-fw li').removeClass('active');
$('.dropdown-menu-fw li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parent().addClass('active');

$('.dropdown-fw').removeClass('selected open');
$('.dropdown-menu-fw li a[href="'+ url+'"]').closest(".dropdown-fw").addClass('open selected');
// $('.dropdown-menu-fw li a').parentsUntil(".dropdown-fw").addClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant
`var url = window.location.href;` instead of `.location`?
That way the whole URL is retrieved.

`.location` retrieves an object.